# Teiid Designer: Always getting "Service jboss.data-source-config.<DS_NAME> is already registered" error when deploying vdb

Tags: jboss, data-virtualization, teiid

when I try to deploy a new virtual database (Teiid9TestConnection_DS is the datasource name, a local MySQL datasource for testing) I always get the following error, even at the very first deploy attempt:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 8)  WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("enable") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("data-source" => "Teiid9TestConnection_DS")
]): org.jboss.msc.service.DuplicateServiceException: Service jboss.data-source-config.Teiid9TestConnection_DS is already registered
  at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceRegistrationImpl.setInstance(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:158)
  at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl.startInstallation(ServiceControllerImpl.java:235)
  at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceContainerImpl.install(ServiceContainerImpl.java:768)
  at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceTargetImpl.install(ServiceTargetImpl.java:223)
  at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ChildServiceTarget.install(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2401)
  at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceTargetImpl.install(ServiceTargetImpl.java:223)
  at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ChildServiceTarget.install(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2401)
  at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceBuilderImpl.install(ServiceBuilderImpl.java:317)
  at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl$ContextServiceBuilder.install(OperationContextImpl.java:1931)
  at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.DataSourceEnable.addServices(DataSourceEnable.java:193)
  at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.DataSourceEnable$1.execute(DataSourceEnable.java:87)
  at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:803)
  at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.doCompleteStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:601)
  at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.completeStepInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:354)
  at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:330)
  at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1183)
  at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.internalExecute(ModelControllerImpl.java:362)
  at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:218)
  at org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler.doExecute(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:201)
  at org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler.access$300(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:128)
  at org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler$1$1.run(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:150)
  at org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler$1$1.run(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:146)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
  at org.jboss.as.controller.AccessAuditContext.doAs(AccessAuditContext.java:92)
  at org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler$1.execute(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:146)
  at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.AbstractMessageHandler$2$1.doExecute(AbstractMessageHandler.java:298)
  at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.AbstractMessageHandler$AsyncTaskRunner.run(AbstractMessageHandler.java:518)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
  at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
```

I have tried different configurations, getting always this error, which doesn't let me deploy the VDB:

- Teiid designer 11.0.0 + Teiid runtime 9.0.6 (WildFly AS + Teiid downloaded in bundle from 9.0 Downloads · Teiid)  + Eclipse 4.6 Neon + Java 1.8.
- Teiid designer 10.1 + Teiid runtime 9.0.6 (WildFly 9.0.6 AS downloaded separately from Teiid, then merged while unzipping) + Eclipse 4.5 Mars + Java 1.8.

Before this main error, the log shows also `Unable to select any database object(s) that match root.`

Can anyone help me understand and overcome the problem?
Thanks in advance.